# How to solve "Environment must have instance profile associated with it." error in Genexus?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, genexus

I am trying to deploy app developed in Genexus using AWS ElasticBeanstalk but,
Error occurred.

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy Start:
> Creating New Environment: EnvironmentName with Stack '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.4.21 running Tomcat 8.5 Java 8'.  This will take some minutes in order to complete.
> .....waiting environment to be ready.... AWS is spinning up the infrastructure.
> Error： Environment 'EnvironmentName' was destroyed. Please wait until Amazon completes the operation and retry later

And when I checked AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it created environment but, has got error message

> Environment must have instance profile associated with it.

When I searched on internet, I have found out that, When we don't use AWS EBS Console, We need to append some parameters to Associate instance profile with environment but,
I couldn't find the way to set those parameters while deploying from Genexus.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to set the instance profile is using `IamInstanceProfile` option in [aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration) in your `.ebextensions`.

In Java SDK you can also use [setOptionSettings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticbeanstalk/model/CreateEnvironmentRequest.html) where you can set that options.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer @Marcin but, I couldn't solve my problem as I use Genexus for the development and want to use AWS ElasticBeanstalk to deploy from Genexus and I don't have these options to add these options in Genexus.